# How can I change the program that Adobe Acrobat uses for editing images?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-acrobat

When I try to edit an image *within* Adobe Acrobat 8.1, it will try to open the image using a Nero program and will fail. I want it to open it with Photoshop, but I can't get it to do that. How do I change the program that Adobe Acrobat uses for editing images?

I'm not talking about changing the default program that opens PDFs; I have Adobe Acrobat 8.1 doing that.

My meaning is that when editing an image *in* a PDF, you select the pencil object icon thing, right click on the image, and then click on Edit Image. I have used it on other computers and it opens with Photoshop, but on mine it opens with some other program.

I don't know how to change that behavior and it is not through the extension manager as I have tried changing the default program for PDFs to Photoshop but my problem isn't fixed.

Comment: I'll assume you're using windows, look at this link for details: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Change-which-programs-Windows-uses-by-default

Comment: That is not what I am looking for...

Comment: Do you mean Adobe Acrobat? Reader is read only. I couldn't find a walk-through for version 8.1, this is for 7, so hopefully it is the same or similar enough: before you can edit from Acrobat, you need to specify the programs you wish to use for editing images and text. You make your choices in the Preferences dialog. Choose Edit > Preferences > TouchUp